# Is it possible to inspect the `HttpRequest` object on MockHttp Callout?

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I have a simple trigger that calls a class with an HTTP callout like this:

**Trigger**

```
trigger OfferChange on Offer__c (after insert, after update) {
   Boolean isSandbox = [SELECT IsSandbox FROM Organization LIMIT 1].IsSandbox;

    Map<String, Object> payload = new Map<String, Object>();
    payload.put('offer', offer);
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        payload.put('change_type', 'update');
    } else if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        payload.put('change_type', 'new');
    } 

   string output = JSON.serialize(payload);
   String devEndpoint = 'https://some-dev-endpoint';
   String prodEndpoint = 'https://some-prod-endpoint';
   String endpoint = isSandbox ? devEndpoint : prodEndpoint;
   OfferChangeHttpRequest.PostAsync(endpoint, output);
}
```

**Http Callout Class**

```
public class OfferChangeHttpRequest {
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void PostAsync(String endpoint, String jsonS) {
        Post(endpoint, jsonS);
    }
    public static void Post(String endpoint, String jsonS) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setbody(jsonS);
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse response = http.send(req);
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to write a test to make sure that the payload is updated appropriately depending on the trigger type, so I thought I could make a Mock Http Class that would stash the `HttpRequest` and inspect it:

```
@isTest
global class OfferChangeHttpRequestMock implements HttpCalloutMock {

    public HttpRequest lastRequest { get; set; }

    global HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request)
    {
        this.lastRequest = request;
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setBody( '{"status":"success"}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```

However, my `lastRequest` variable is always null so this test always fails:

```
@isTest
public class TestOfferChange {
    @isTest static void TestOfferChangeInsert() {
        OfferChangeHttpRequestMock mocker = new OfferChangeHttpRequestMock();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mocker);
        Test.startTest();

        // test insert trigger
        insert offer;

        // This assertion always fails
        // System.assert(mocker.lastRequest != null);
```

Is it possible or is there any easier to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `Test.stopTest` to get your `@future` method to run synchronously:

```
// setup

Test.startTest();
    // call future method
Test.stopTest();

// now your code has finished executing
```